# Python os.popen() returns running process count incremented by 1

Tags: python, linux, popen, python-os

I have tried to get process count by using `ps`, when I execute command on my linux terminal it returns correct count.
But when I am executing same command in python shell using `os.popen()`, then the returned count is always incremented by `one`

```
root@dev:/home/admin# ps -ef | grep some_process | wc -l
1
root@dev:/home/admin# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('ps -ef | grep some_process | wc -l').read()
'2\n'
>>>
```

Comment: try using: `ps -ef | grep [s]ome_process | wc -l`  -first letter of process name in []

Comment: `ps -ef | grep [s]ome_process | wc -l` now this returns 0,  its not counting grep process now @Drako,  count should be one, as in when we are doing grep it creates new process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.popen` would have launched the process `/bin/sh -c 'ps -ef | grep some_precess | wc -l'` which will also be counted as a process matching your condition.

Instead try the cmd `ps -ef | grep some_process | grep -v grep | wc -l` both from shell and python, so that you be accidentally counting this launched process

Comment: Thanks! @Sunitha that works for me,  Can you able to explain in detail with modifying your answer , what happens in your command

Comment: You should be able to understand better if you get rid of the `wc -l` at the end of your commands. Try both your version and mine, on shell and python without `wc -l`.

Comment: Yeah I got to know that, it not counting grep process in your case, I just want to you add information about `grep -v grep` in answer , so it is helpful for others as well

Answer (score 1):

First, let's examine what `os.popen('ps -ef | grep some_process | wc -l').read()` does. It spawns a shell, with the given command line in its argument list. That then spawns a pipeline of three processes, and among those `ps` collects the list of processes. At this point, at least the first shell and the `grep` have `some_process` in their argument list; possibly the third pipeline process too, if it hasn't yet `exec`uted `wc`. `grep` filters the list, and `wc` counts the results. Note that the only reason the arguments were even in the listing for `grep` to find is the use of `-f`, which might have been redundant since `wc` doesn't care.

This should make it clear why someone suggested `[s]ome_process`; this pattern doesn't match itself, and would exclude all of those 2-3 processes, *assuming the [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) didn't work*. It needs quotes to work should there happen to exist a file named `some_process`.

There may be far more reliable methods, however. We're already running a Python process, so we can easily count things, and `ps` has switches to select specific processes, for instance `ps -C some_process` to select on command name. Thus a more discriminate form of the task might be:

```
subprocess.check_output(["ps", "--no-heading", "-C", "python"]).count(b'\n')
```

Check for other relevant switches to command such as `ps` using `man`.

Comment: Thanks @YannVernier, Great explanation